# NextJS API directory and useState

Tags: reactjs, json, forms, next.js

I am trying to get

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
const [pointdata, setPointData] = React.useState('');
```

in my API directory. however, everytime I try and run the code I get `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState'`

However, the same code there works fine when it is in a `/page/myfile.js`

How can I put `useState` and `useEffect` in an API directory or is their another way to do this?

Why is it an API file because we are posting form data to this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default async function gll(req, res) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
  const [pointdata, setPointData] = React.useState('');
        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use `useState` and/or `useEffect` in api directory.
Since React is a front-end library you can only use it's hooks in client-side code i.e. `/page/[fileName].js`. The code that you write inside `/api/[fileName].js` is back-end code hence you cannot use React.js hooks there

According to official Next.js documentation.

> API routes provide a solution to build your API with Next.js.
>
> Any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be
> treated as an API endpoint instead of a page.

For more info. visit [API Routes | Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)